# Creating directories in the browser with JS in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, forms, file-upload

I am uploading files from my browser via a form that has the directory option to a Laravel application on the front end I am reading the `webkitRelativePath` to group the files together. My question is how would I create multiple directories to upload this via the same form but in the groups that I have made? Is this possible and if not what is the closest solution? Thanks

Note: All of these files are in the same input I need to get them from that input and make more and spread the files across the inputs, how do I move the files from a single directory input to others?